# Exception occurred in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I get an exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in ASP.NET MVC when I post form-data with more than one models.

This is my "ViewModel" class:

```
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblGender> Genders  { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblCountry> Countries { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the `Edit` action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
{
            var customer = _context.Customers
.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel()
            {
                Customer = customer,
                Genders = _context.tblGenders.ToList(),
                Countries = _context.tblCountries.ToList()
            };
            return View("Edit",viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
{
            var cust = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
            TryUpdateModel(cust);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
}
```

`Create.cshtml`:

The error occurs in this section

```
   <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Gender)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.Gender, new    SelectList(Model.Genders, "Id", "GenderName"), "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this piece of code, your variable customer can be null:

```
var customer = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

In this piece of code, you are assigning that very variable to your model.Customer:

```
var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel()
            {
                Customer = customer,
```

In this piece of code, you are using model.Customer as if you are sure it is not null:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Gender)
```

Out of many other possibilities, this is the most obvious null-ref I can find.
To fix it you can do something like this:

```
var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel()
            {
                Customer = customer ?? new Customer(),
```

or this:

```
var customer = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
if (customer == null) {
  return view("CustomerNotFound"); //or some other way to display your error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Object reference exception. Have you created instances of the objects that you're using?
e.g:

```
private readonly CustomerViewModel _customerViewModel;
_customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
```

Comment: Yes, he has. Line 6: var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel()